# Old CRM data is shown after refreshing page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, dynamics-crm

I'm building simple `ASP.NET MVC` web page that show all active accounts from `MS Dynamics CRM`.

Basically page works well if I compile it and run (with F5). Problem appears when I go to Microsoft Dynamics CRM web page, login and then change one account status from active to inactive. Now when I refresh page that I'm building, I get same old results.

I have tried refreshing (F5), hard refreshing (Ctrl + F5), disposing `xrm` object before returning view, but nothing worked. So I think I misunderstood something.

**Controllers/HomeControler.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    using (var xrm = new XrmServiceContext("Xrm"))
    {
        var accounts = from a in xrm.AccountSet
                       where a.StateCode == 0
                       select a;

        List<AccountModel> accountModels = new List<AccountModel>();

        foreach (var account in accounts)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(c+"\t"+account.Id+"\t"+account.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(account.Address1_Composite);
            accountModels.Add(new AccountModel(
                account.Id.ToString(),
                account.Name,
                account.Address1_Composite));
        }

        ViewBag.Title = "Page Title";
        ViewBag.AccountModels = accountModels;
    }
    return View();
}
```

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = @"~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover">
        <caption><h2>Active Accounts</h2></caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Account ID</th>
                <th>Account Name</th>
                <th>Account Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                foreach (var accountModel in ViewBag.AccountModels)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@accountModel.Id</td>
                        <td>@accountModel.Name</td>
                        <td>@accountModel.Address</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**
Now I noticed that only first refresh after "Rebuild and Run" actually refresh site. Is this IIS Express (I'm doing this locally) fault?

Comment: In action you have new data or old data like in view?

Comment: @adricadar Old data same as in view

Comment: Hmmm, have you tried to delete the record and see if the information is still the same or change some data?

Comment: @Sxntk I changed some data but old data was displayed

Comment: I mean, not only the state code, the address, the name...

Comment: @Sxntk Yes I did, nothing changed

Comment: If this is not a CRM problem I can't help you anymore, looks like you are calling one time the services and  it keeps alive with the old data in the view.

Comment: Maybe misconfigured `XrmServiceContext`? Did you check your config against https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695805.aspx especially `InstanceMode`?

Answer (score 2):

It is important what you have configured in web.config for the XRM context. By default, the service is instantiated using the `CachedOrganizationService`, which, as its name implies, caches all data.

To disable caching, use the following configuration (replacing the `Xrm.XrmServiceContext, Xrm` with your own ServiceContext):

```xml
<microsoft.xrm.client>
  <contexts>
   <!-- Replace with your actual ServiceContext -->
   <add name="Xrm" type="Xrm.XrmServiceContext, Xrm" serviceName="Xrm" instanceMode="PerRequest"/>
  </contexts>
  <services>
   <!-- Disable cache -->
   <add name="Xrm" type="Microsoft.Xrm.Client.Services.OrganizationService, Microsoft.Xrm.Client"/>
  </services>
</microsoft.xrm.client>
```

For more information about the default configuration, check [Developer extensions context object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695819.aspx) on MSDN.